# Call an ActionScript function from Javascript

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3, actionscript

I want to call an Action Script function from javascript. But also I need the ActionScript function to return a value to the javascript call.

This is what I want to accomplish.

```
 /* JS CODE */

 var str = getStringFromFlash();
 alert(str);
```

getStringFromFlash should be a function defined in ActionScript that can return a value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On the Flash side:

```
ExternalInterface.addCallback("getValue", getValue);
```

Where `getValue()` is the function that returns the string.

Then on the JavaScript side:

```
var flashObject = document.getElementById("myFlashObject");
var str = flashObject.getValue();
alert(str);
```

See API documentation for the `ExternalInterface` class for a more complete example.

Answer (score 1):

[`ExternalInterface.addCallback()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html#addCallback%28%29)